# The expression 'x' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation

Tags: .net, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on a dotnet core project where I am using repository pattern and using the repositories inside a mediator handler.

I have a one method inside a repository which return multiple records from database:

```cs
public List<T> GetAll(List<Expression<Func<T, object>>>? includes = null)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = _dbSet.AsQueryable();

    if (includes != null)
    {
        query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
    }

    return query.AsNoTracking().ToList();
}
```

I am providing includes in handler like below:

```cs
public async Task<List<Office>> Handle(Office request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var includes = new List<Expression<Func<Office, object>>>
    {
        c => c.OfficeAddresses,
        c => c.OfficeDepartments.Select(d => d.Department).Select(cc => cc.Phones),
    };

    return await _repository.GetAll(includes: includes);
}
```

I am getting error:

> The expression 'c.OfficeDepartments.AsQueryable().Select(x => x.Department)' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations

Comment: Are you coming from EF6 ("classic" EF)? List of `Expression<Func<T, object>>`cannot be used in EF Core to represent their `Include` / `ThenInclude` pattern, because as the error message says, `Select` cannot be used inside `Include` expression for resolving elements of a related collections as it was in EF6. EF Core requires different signature and calling the include part of the repository method.

Comment: How can I add multiple thenIncludes in the repository method so that it becomes a reusable method?

Comment: In my beautiful world I do not use generic repostory pattern. Can you do that also by removing this unnecessary abstraction?

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework (Core) is already itself a repository/unit of work. So writing a repo/UOW wrapper around EF is, to be blunt, pointless. In fact it's worse than pointless, it's actively harmful, because the wrapper you've presented doesn't even abstract away any of the underlying EF concepts. A handler should know nothing about the underlying data store, but your horrible not-abstraction forces it to.

Take your `IRepository` and throw it in the bin, then rewrite your code in the following way:

- A `Store` layer, with methods that each accept a request-type DTO/POCO containing details of the data to fetch. These methods use EF Core to communicate with the DB and return one or more DTO/POCO. **These methods are wholly self-contained and do not expose any detail of the actual data store interface being used.**
- A `Handler` layer that depends on the `Store`. The `Handler` constructs the requests to send to the DB, and maps these to responses. A `Handler` method may call multiple `Store` methods to accomplish what it needs.